# Git reference in chm format

Tags: git, reference, chm

Is there any version of git documentation in chm format?

I know that I can compile it from existing html reference, but it takes time to do it properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not that I know of, also is there any specific reason you want it in chm?

Comment: @OneOfOne: The specific reason is that I'm on windows and all my manuals are in chm

Comment: Here's a list of all available Git docs : https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitDocumentation

Comment: There is NO documentation available in chm format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reference in chm format, unfortunately. Probably I should create one.